Error while updating Cybersource certificate on Java deployment
I am receiving below error after updating Cybersource p12 certificate (downloaded from their merchant portal) on server (app is deployed through a docker image):
com.cybersource.security.exception.SecuritySystemException: Security Data : A JSAFE_MAC object of PBE/HMAC/SHA256/PKCS12V1PBE-1-160 is not available on any of the devices. (Native/Java)

I am using java version 8.0.191 (< 8.3). I looked into various resources, but unable to figure out the meaning of the error and the remedy.

The new PKCS#12 is generated using new OpenSSL which causes compatibility issues with older Java/sdk.
You could try downloading an old version of the KeyStore Explorer(I used 5.4.4) and try to re-export it as PKCS#12. You can change the keystore type to JKS, save, re-open the file, change the type back to PKCS#12 and save.
You might also need to set the keystore password and private key password to the merchant id if you also have an older version of the Cybersource SDK.
